# Order an array of objects based in other array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Lets say I have an array of products:

```
const Products = [
{ id: 123, productName: "Portable Tabletop Game", quantity: 12 },
{ id: 456, productName: "Gift Card", quantity: 23 },
{ id: 789, productName: "Box of Chocolates", quantity: 8 },
{ id: 012, productName: "Gift Box", quantity: 4 },
{ id: 098, productName: "Balloons", quantity: 15 },
{ id: 765, productName: "Music Box", quantity: 30 }];
```

and I have another, smaller array where I store the order of the products on my page:

```
const orderItems = [
{ order: 1, productId: 021 },
{ order: 2, productId: 765 }, 
{ order: 3, productId: 123 }];
```

And I want my Products array in such a way they are ordered like the orderItems array defines, like so:

```
const Products = [
{ id: 012, productName: "Gift Box", quantity: 4 },
{ id: 765, productName: "Music Box", quantity: 30 },
{ id: 123, productName: "Portable Tabletop Game", quantity: 12 },
{ id: 456, productName: "Gift Card", quantity: 23 },
{ id: 789, productName: "Box of Chocolates", quantity: 8 },
{ id: 098, productName: "Balloons", quantity: 15 }];
```

and I want the products who do not have a corresponding `orderItem` to be at the end of the array, is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do it using **Array.filter()** and **Array.some()** method simply. **Array.filter()** method will return an array of the products matching with the item in orderItems whereas **Array.some()** method will simple check or match if element exists.

```
const Products = [
{ id: 123, productName: "Portable Tabletop Game", quantity: 12 },
{ id: 456, productName: "Gift Card", quantity: 23 },
{ id: 789, productName: "Box of Chocolates", quantity: 8 },
{ id: 012, productName: "Gift Box", quantity: 4 },
{ id: 098, productName: "Balloons", quantity: 15 },
{ id: 765, productName: "Music Box", quantity: 30 }];const Products = [
{ id: 123, productName: "Portable Tabletop Game", quantity: 12 },
{ id: 456, productName: "Gift Card", quantity: 23 },
{ id: 789, productName: "Box of Chocolates", quantity: 8 },
{ id: 012, productName: "Gift Box", quantity: 4 },
{ id: 098, productName: "Balloons", quantity: 15 },
{ id: 765, productName: "Music Box", quantity: 30 }];

const orderItems = [
{ order: 1, productId: 012},
{ order: 2, productId: 765 }, 
{ order: 3, productId: 123 }];
let OrderItem = [];
OrderItem = Products.filter((item,key)=>{
    return orderItems[key] && orderItems[key]['productId'] && Products.some((ele)=> ele.id === orderItems[key]['productId'])
    console.log(OrderItem)

})
```

Comment: Please let me know if this works for you.Thanks Give it a thumbs up. :)

Comment: Well, it certanly does filter the products that appear in the orderItems array...but it doesn't order them according to their value, if you can add something to order the results, I will be thankful!

Comment: feel free to edit your answer